# database configuration does not specify adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to connect to a mysql database. The problem is that the application works for weeks, and then randomly I get this message. When I get this error message the application is not able to reconnect to the database until I restart it.

I'm using a configuration file to connect to the database, and the adapter is specified...the database configuration is not generated at runtime.

Do you have any idea on what is going on?

Comment: What platform? Can you post full stack trace/log entries? When you "restart it", do you mean the app or the db?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions given around here. I'm currently having this problem on Heroku with Rails 3.2.6. When `RACK_ENV=development` or `RAILS_ENV=production` everything is fine, but when `RACK_ENV=production` and `RAILS_ENV` is unset, as I prefer it to be, then I get this message. The discussion here helped me find this unique combination of circumstances. Will report back when I know more.

Comment: Actually, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661115/on-heroku-rake-dbmigrate-fails-with-database-configuration-does-not-specify-a tracks more precisely my problem. Will post my findings there later.

Comment: I had inserted comments ("#") into a database.yml file. This, apparently, is a bad idea.

Comment: Check your database.yml file. Make sure that "adapter" is in either  default or specified in the environments

  default: &default
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3

Answer (score 69):

when I tried to run a command line script (let's say 'my_script' here), the same error happened.  The reasons were:

1. There is only production environment there.
2. I missed to set RAILS_ENV for the command line.

So, the following is the solution in my case:

> $ RAILS_ENV=production my_script

Comment: $ export RAILS_ENV=production should be better.

Comment: also if you just need it for a `rake`command or something similar you can pass it directly as a parameter, for example: `rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: For bundler: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec ...` - in my case `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Worked for me when I ran `RAILS_ENV=production rails c` but did not work when I ran `rails c RAILS_ENV=production`.  Setting the env first is the trick.

Answer (score 36):

I just had this problem, and it was caused by a typo in my configration.yml.

I originally had this:

```
production:
  adapter:mysql
```

When I meant to have this:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
```

That one little space between adapter: and mysql makes the difference.

Comment: that was exactly my problem. That was brilliant. Since there was no tabs I assumed that a lack of whitespace should not be a problem. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 12):

Another possible cause:

In Rails 3.2.x, `establish_connection` has a default argument set from the environment:

From [connection_specification.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.8/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb#L127):

```
def self.establish_connection(spec = ENV["DATABASE_URL"])
  resolver = ConnectionSpecification::Resolver.new spec, configurations
  spec = resolver.spec
```

The way `ConnectionSpecification::Resolver` works depends on `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` giving a `nil` if not set.  (Normally, it would be something like `'postgres://...'`).

So, if you happen to have misconfigured `DATABASE_URL` such that `ENV['DATABASE_URL'] == ''`, that will give you `database configuration does not specify adapter`.

Comment: I am using `docker-compose ` so I did this `DATABASE_URL: database_service/app_development` where `databases_service` is the other container name and `app_development` is the database. I am expecting that `docker` link the containers together but for some reason I getting this error only in this setup

PS: I did this before and it works so that's why I am confused

Comment: Yep, the problem for me was that I need to put the full URL in `DATABASE_URL`

Answer (score 7):

I had this error when I mistakenly started rails server with

> sudo rails s -e "Production" -p 80

and I should have started rails with

> sudo rails s -e "production" -p 80

Answer (score 4):

I found another thing that can cause this problem: "mixing in" another YAML node using `&` and `*`.

I was originally doing something like the following to facilitate local, per-develop, Git-ignored config files:

http://blog.lathi.net/articles/2006/03/02/config-database-yml-goodness-for-teams

But, after some debugging, I came to find out that `establish_connection` was for some reason being called with only the mixed-in key-value pairs and not the main ones. I.e. `adapter`, `host`, and `database` were not being passed in. I have no idea why, and this used to work for me.

Anyhow, instead of mixing in another YAML node, I now put the entire `development` and `test` hashes in the local config file, and `establish_connection` is once again being called correctly.

Answer (score 4):

For me, this command resolved the issue.

rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production

Answer (score 3):

I've found a couple of clues that this might be related to older library (ActiveRecord) or gem versions. For example, [problems with fixtures even though rest of app seems okay](http://wrath.rubyonrails.org/pipermail/rails/2006-January/009470.html) (after an upgrade) or [this trac ticket](http://dev.rubyonrails.org/browser/trunk/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb?rev=7771), which "stops gems from requiring an adapter from an old Active Record gem". Both of these are old, though, but it might be worth making sure your gems are up to date (if possible).

Are you using the native rails MySQL adapter by any chance? This is now deprecated under rails, but it's conceivable it's still limping along.

I've taken a very quick look at `connection_specification.rb`, too, which is where this error is coming from, and my best guess is that a reconnect is failing... but why (since it was obviously okay when you first started the app)? Are you doing something wild like calling `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` in your application controller (or elsewhere)?

Or perhaps something like: script runner is called from cron in the dead of night when the connection has dropped. Unfortunately, the runner is invoked with an incorrect `RAILS_ENV`. Thus the wrong stanza is read from `database.yml`, and that stanza contains an invalid `adapter:`?

Comment: Solved it for me. Wrong environment, pointing to a stanza that didn't exist in my database.yml file. xD

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error, by typing in the following command:

```
db:migrate RAILS_ENV=product
```

Should've been:

```
db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get this error while deploying with Capistrano. Make sure you are setting the correct RAILS_ENV via

```
set :rails_env, 'production'
```

For example I was not explicitly setting the Rails environment in for the Capistrano staging deployment configuration. And thus Capistrano used 'staging' as the RAILS_ENV, resulting in the above error. Setting it to production like above in the staging.rb file solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Do remember that RAILS_ENV=staging will look for a staging specification in your database.yml just as setting RAILS_ENV=production will look for a production specification in database.yml file.

Provide database configs, as shown below, for every rails environment you target using, for example

```
bundle exec cap staging deploy

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: rails
  username: rails
  password: pass
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

staging:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: rails
  username: rails
  password: pass
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember to use the C-Based ruby gem for mysql. The ruby-based is unstable for production.

Try installing the gem

```
gem install mysql
```

Remember to copy **libmySQL.dll** into the ruby bin directory.

Comment: uhm my web server is an ubuntu one. 
Trying to install the mysql gem I get this list:

1. mysql 2.7.3 (mswin32)
2. mysql 2.7.1 (mswin32)
3. mysql 2.7 (ruby)
4. mysql 2.6 (ruby)

Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 1):

I had this error with another problem;  I had specified 'development' twice, and 'test' not at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are alot of bad tutorials out there on the internet that show yaml files like so:

```
development:
encoding: utf
database: dbname
...etc
```

YAML files are case sensitive and require TWO SPACES for the inner contents of each given db-type attribute. Like so:

```
development:
  encoding: utf
  database: dbname
  ...etc
```

---

UPDATE: I got this error ***again*** today. My VPS server had installed Rails 3.2.8 when my app was running Rails 3.2.6.

Definitely check your Gemfile and your database.yml file (of course). The problem here is clearly stated---Rails is not communicating with your database specifically due to an adapter (aka gem)

Comment: I found that the entry for my environment at the bottom of the file was formatted correctly, but an extra space in a previous entry was the problem.  development ran fine because it was before the incorrectly formatted entry, so check other entries if you are sure yours is proper.

Answer (score 1):

We had this issue with one of our older apps. Someone had created a boutique named environment, that even if RAIL_ENV was set to production, it was looking for a database configuration called `legacy_<RAIL_ENV>`, so I had to make a database environment called `legacy_production` for this app to work.

If you are maintain someone else's app, I would look for a copy of this app's `database.yml` that is working, perhaps it has some oddly named configuration. You can search your codebase for `establish_connection` to see if it is defining some strange variant.

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem due to the 'multiple database support issue'. In my `app/model` folder, there is a file defined a redundant database connection:

```
class CacheCleanerActiveRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "cache_cleaner_#{Rails.env}"
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

but this database is not found in my database.yml ( because it's not used at all ).

so the solution is quit simple: remove this file and everything is fine !

Comment: This is original solution.

Comment: `establish_connection` expects a config hash in Rails v5.2: https://devdocs.io/rails~5.2/activerecord/connectionhandling#method-i-establish_connection

Answer (score 1):

You may have an error like:

```
RAILS_ENV= test
```

A space after the equals sign is not allowed, change it to:

```
RAILS_ENV=test
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me, finally I found that `RAILS_ENV` is case sensitive, in my enviroment I set
`RAILS_ENV=DEVELOPMENT` , which is wrong, the value of `RAILS_ENV` must be **lowercase**.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=DEVELOPMENT rails server webrick
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in DEVELOPMENT on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true

Exiting
/home/fangxing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in `resolve_symbol_c
onnection': 'DEVELOPMENT' database is not configured. Available: ["default", "development", "test", "production"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
        from /home/fangxing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:211:in `res
olve_connection'



$ RAILS_ENV=development rails server webrick
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is outdated/buggy. (To disable warnings, set RUBY_DEP_GEM_SILENCE_WARNINGS=1)
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is: 2.3.0 (buggy). Recommendation: install 2.3.1.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-07-20 16:41:09] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-07-20 16:41:09] INFO  ruby 2.3.0 (2015-12-25) [x86_64-linux]
[2016-07-20 16:41:09] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=19881 port=3000
```

Comment: Please do not post text as images (unsearcheable), instead copy-paste the text in your post. Thanks.

Comment: Got it, Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

`rails -e "production"` is okay

only `rails -e production` returns error

```
database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

Answer (score 0):

call `rake assets:precompile:all`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most likely issue to cause this error, but here it is just in case.

My problem was that I was building the database settings in a `Hash` using symbols as keys and then serializing it with `#to_yaml` to `database.yaml`. ActiveRecord expects the environment names to be `Strings`, not `Symbols`, so it wasn't picking up the database settings when reading the generated file. I fixed it by using string keys in the hash.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails4, commenting the line `fetch(:default_env).merge!(rails_env: 'production')` in `production.rb` and adding `set :rails_env, :production` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the environment when running the server or command as your database.yml file may have only production adapter while simply runnig rake db:migrate for example will take environment variable as development.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, I just got this error because I natively created a parametrised Rails runner script that takes an email address, and named the command line option `-e` -- which of course is the one the Rails runner uses for the environment. So it was trying to find an environment configuration that matched the email address!

Luckily, just before the `ActiveRecord` error mentioned in the title, it gave me an error message that helped me twig what the problem actually was:

```
You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for your test@example.com environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :log, :notify or :stderr at config/environments/test@example.com.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of `adapter` I had `adaptor` and got this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message when upgrading from Rails 4 to 5. I was calling

```
establish_connection "myconnection"
```

where `"myconnection"` is a valid key in my `database.yml`. However, passing this parameter as a string is apparently no longer supported. Using a symbol instead got rid of the problem.

Comment: Use caution when passing `establish_connection` a string! It expects a config hash: https://devdocs.io/rails~5.2/activerecord/connectionhandling#method-i-establish_connection

Answer (score 0):

I got this from **copying and pasting** `sudo rails server webrick –e production -d` from documentation into the CLI.

I'll shut the door on my way out

Answer (score 0):

Checklist

1. Check if `:environment` is missing in your task `task task_name_here: :environment do`
2. Try running it with `rake namespace_name:task_name_here RAILS_ENV=development`