# On heroku, rake db:migrate fails with "database configuration does not specify adapter"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I've followed the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app?version=3.2#sec%3adeploying_the_demo_app) up to the linked point.

Here's the shell output:

```
jrhorn424 at hook in ~/Learning/rails/rails-tutorial/demo_app on master
$ heroku run rake db:migrate          
Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.2

### Snip ###

Migrating to CreateUsers (20120310145100)
Migrating to CreateMicroposts (20120311052021)
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter

Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've consulted the [Heroku quick start](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3#rake), and done a bit of Googling. I suspected the problem was with `config/database.yml` since that is full of references to `sqlite3` in my development environment. However, on the server, the same file includes these lines, among others:

```
adapter = uri.scheme
adapter = "postgresql" if adapter == "postgres"
```

Adding data through the deployed application succeeds, but running `heroku run rake db:migrate` still fails.

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Comment: Heroku overrides the database.yml file to use its own PostgreSQL instance. Could you please add your Gemfile to this question?

Comment: Thanks, @RyanBigg. Gemfile added. As noted, the `database.yml` on the server seems to include the correct adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend dropping your databases with:

```
bundle exec rake db:drop:all
```

If you are going to be hosting on heroku, go ahead and use postgres for all of your environments. Delete the sqlite gem and just include

```
gem 'pg'
```

near the top of your Gemfile.

Peform a:

```
bundle
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Try to commit and push again (you know how to do that already).

Let me know if that doesn't work.

PS, here is what my database.yml file looks like:

```
# PostgreSQL v0.8.x
#   gem install pg
 development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: health_development
  pool: 5
  username: volpine
  password: password

  # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
  # re-generated from your development database when you run         "rake".
  # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
 test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: health_test
  pool: 5
  username: volpine
  password: password

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: health_production
  pool: 5
  username: volpine
  password: password
```

Comment: That's probably good advice, since [Heroku recommends](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-do-i-use-sqlite3-for-development) doing just that. However, as far as I can tell, this won't help with the remote call to migrate with `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

Comment: wbat about attempting a:    
    heroku run rake db:push

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion (well, I did `heroku db:push`) lead me to my solution.

Answer (score 3):

For me i faced this error when i tried to open rails console in production,

When i gave,

```
bundle exec rails c RAILS_ENV=production
```

it throws the error

```
 `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

but it works when i gave,

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this and found that manually setting RAILS_ENV did the trick for me:

```
heroku run RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran `heroku db:push`, I got a [taps error](https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/issues/92) that lead me to switch to using ruby 1.9.2. After switching versions and starting a new app, I no longer receive the error from `heroku run rake db:migrate`, and everything works as expected.

**Update:** I've just been informed that version mismatching shouldn't matter for `db:migrate`. It definitely mattered for `db:push`, so I'm not sure what was wrong. In any case, when I initialize a new app with the same Gemfile and 1.9.2, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was happening because I removed the RAILS_ENV environment variable from my heroku app and only left a RACK_ENV one.

Adding the RAILS_ENV=production did fix the issue:

```
heroku config:add RAILS_ENV=production --app XXXX-production
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't look at your database.yml file, it looks at DATABASE_URL - if that's not set, or there is a typo in it, then you'll get that error.