# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished on rails3 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to upgrade from rails 2.3 to rails 3, and have finished the checklist of things for `rake rails:upgrade:check`, however, when I try to start my rails console, I get the following error, when I try and access any table:

```
irb(main):010:0> Game.all
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
    from /Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:317:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:97:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
    from /Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/base.rb:602:in `quoted_table_name'
    from /Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:275:in `build_select'
    from /Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:189:in `build_arel'
    from /Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:149:in `arel'
    from /Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/relation.rb:64:in `to_a'
    from /Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:143:in `all'
    from /Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.20/lib/active_record/base.rb:444:in `all'
    from (irb):10
    from /Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/ttt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm using the mysql, upgrading from to the mysql2 gem, with my gem file looking like:

```
gem "rails", "3.0.20"
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.17'
```

I've also updated my `database.yml` to

```
development_default: &development_default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  pool: 5
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *development_default
  database: some_database
  username: some_user
  password: some_password
  host: some.domain.com
  port: 4000
```

I'm able to switch back to my rails 2 branch and run the code fine, so it's definitely something with my upgrade code. Any pointers what the problem is or where to look next?

Comment: Oh, and same happens when running the server and accessing a page that queries the db (the server does run though, so that's positive).

Comment: [A lots of reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413659/database-configuration-does-not-specify-adapter), as described here...

Comment: The problem was that my `database.yml` had a stray <%= %> with a variable that didn't exist anymore. Even though it was commented out with a `#`, the yml still failed to load. Removing this commented code fixed the issue.