# can't run rake or rails console on vps

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a demo Rails app up and running on a VPS thanks to Ryan Bates' deploying to a VPS episode on Railscasts. On my server I created a directory structure like this `/home/username/apps` and the application was deployed to `/home/username/apps/appname.` Inside the app name folder are three more folders created by Ryan's script (I presume)

```
current  releases  shared
```

and inside the `current` folder is the usual Rails directory. If I cd into the `current` folder and run `rails c` or `rake db:seed` I get the error

```
 configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

being triggered from the shared directory

```
 apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters
```

I find this an unusual error to get since the demo application (which is scaffolding) is saving newly created entries and listing them out, so I'm assuming there's something wrong with how I'm trying to run rake and rails console commands rather than something wrong with my declaration of the adapter.

Can you tell me what it might be?

Note, there's already a question [database configuration does not specify adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413659/database-configuration-does-not-specify-adapter) that deals with this general topic, however, the answers to that question seem to deal with situations where the database isn't working at all, however, in my situation it seems that's not the case. Therefore, I distinguish this question from that thread.

This is my database.yml file

```
production:
  adapter:  postgresql
  encoding:  unicode
  database:  dodeploy_production
  pool:  5
  host:  localhost
  username:  michael
  password:  secretpassword
```

This is the script Ryan uses to deploy. I'm including it because maybe there's some information in here that will help you understand something I'm missing.

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

server "198XXXX", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "dodeploy"
set :user, "michael"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:Username/appname.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

Error

When I run `rails c` (or `rake db:seed`) I'm getting this

```
home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:52:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:46:in `resolve_string_connection'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:30:in `spec'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:39:in `establish_connection'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:170:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/base.rb:322:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/base.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:61:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:188:in `call'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:188:in `block in run_console_blocks'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:188:in `each'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:188:in `run_console_blocks'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application.rb:264:in `block in run_console_blocks'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:17:in `each'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:17:in `each'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application.rb:264:in `run_console_blocks'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:431:in `load_console'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `new'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands.rb:66:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Update

I wasn't sure why Ryan created database.example.yml in the Railscast. He didn't configure it and I just left it as a copy of the original database.yml file before I added the username and password.

database.example.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dodeploy_development
  pool: 5
  password:
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dodeploy_test
  pool: 5
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dodeploy_production
  pool: 5
  password:
```

This is the nginx.conf file

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.dodeploy.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  # server_name example.com;
  root /home/michael/apps/dodeploy/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Update.

this is the method from connection_specification.rb

```
     def resolve_hash_connection(spec) # :nodoc:
          spec = spec.symbolize_keys

          raise(AdapterNotSpecified, "database configuration does not specify adapter") unless spec.key?(:adapter)

          path_to_adapter = "active_record/connection_adapters/#{spec[:adapter]}_adapter"
          begin
            require path_to_adapter
          rescue Gem::LoadError => e
            raise Gem::LoadError, "Specified '#{spec[:adapter]}' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `$
          rescue LoadError => e
 raise LoadError, "Could not load '#{path_to_adapter}'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is$
          end

          adapter_method = "#{spec[:adapter]}_connection"

          ConnectionSpecification.new(spec, adapter_method)
        end
```

Comment: I guess each rails error has complete information with line, etc. Could you provide that?

Comment: Did you read the output of cap deploy? It probably says something like "Now edit the config files in ..." How does your `config/database.example.yml` file look?

Comment: Do you have a `rails_env` line in your nginx.conf file?

Comment: @MichałSzyndel I wasn't sure why Ryan Bates created the database.example.yml file. He didn't provide instructions for it, and I just left it in its original state, which is a copy of the original database.yml file before I added my username and password . see OP for update.

Comment: @depa I added nginx.conf to the OP. Does it look ok? Thanks

Comment: SO, from what I understand this line `put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"` copies database.example.yml to shared/database.yml which is used by the server. YOu could either change it to copy regular database.yml or edit example file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work by specifying the production environment when I ran the commands

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails console

RAILS_ENV=production rake db:seed
```

I found this unusual since the app was working.