# rake db:test:clone RAILS_ENV="test" fails, Odd Error: database configuration does not specify adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running `rake db:test:clone RAILS_ENV="test"` and I get the error: `database configuration does not specify adapter`.

My database.yml is as follows:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: mydb_development
  username: mydbuser
  password:
  allow_concurrency: true
  pool: 5
  min_messages: warning

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: mydb_test
  username: mydbuser
  password:
  pool: 5
```

ps. `rake db:test:prepare RAILS_ENV="test"` returns the same error.

On "test" I am not sure if host is required. I deleted it and tried again just in case. Any ideas?

**Update**

When I execute `rake db:create:all` I get a notice:

```
mydb_development already exists
```

Isn't it suppose to also return mydb_test already exists?

I run `bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test` and got the same error.

Comment: Sounds like a weird one.  Try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13773301/1026898 .  It seems like the problem could be solved with something in that question, or you repeatedly made a typo when trying to use your command (seems unlikely since you spelled everything correctly here).

Comment: @Ecnalyr Thanks. I tried their solution but nothing helped. I double checked for typos. Can you check the update please?

Comment: "Isn't it suppose to also return mydb_test already exists?" Yes it is.

Comment: I fear it may come off as condescending, but here is the database.yaml file of my current project I'm working with (I'm sure you have others you can reference, but who knows): https://gist.github.com/ecnalyr/fd086611990dce9e3a96 .  Maybe you'll get lucky and that'll help.

Comment: tried it. same error. Also bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per our IRC conversation!

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create

RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 4):

try to set environment variable before the actual command

```
RAILS_ENV="test" rake db:test:clone
```