# When using ActiveRecord::Database::Tasks outside of Rails, what do I need to configure to avoid a development database not configured error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm calling `ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.load_schema_current(:sql, file)` in a Ruby file script (essentially it's a Thor task) in a Ruby off Rails app and I get the following error:

```
/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in `resolve_symbol_connection': 'development' database is not configured. Available: [] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

Does ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks give me the functions I need to set up a default database configuration outside of rails (I'm assuming I need to provide info similar to what's in database.yml in Rails)?  If so, what are the functions I would need to call?  I'm looking at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Tasks/DatabaseTasks.html  but it's a bit unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Before load the schema, you need to load the database configuration (like the database.yml):

```
DatabaseTasks.database_configuration = YAML.load_file('my_database_config.yml')
```

Comment: I'm still getting this error, though I checked the YAML file is loading..how do I specify RAILS_ENV a la http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413659/database-configuration-does-not-specify-adapter ??

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work in a non-Rails project with the following...

```
db_config = YAML.load_file('path/to/database.yml')
ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.load_schema_for(
  db_config, :ruby, 'path/to/schema.rb')
```